# Fabric.js Image covering Text after moving it

Tags: fabricjs

Am trying yo use fabric.js to create one of those web apps people use to design phone cases and stuff but am having an issue with ITEXT and image when ever i add an image and add text to the canvas the  image just covers it and it doesnt show

here is the code for image

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, function (oImg) {
                    canvas.clear();
                    canvas.add(oImg);
                });
```

here s the code for the IText

```
    $('#add').click(function () {
        canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
            left: 50,
            top: 100,
            fontFamily: 'Tangerine arial black',
            fill: '#000',
            fontSize: 20,
            paintFirst: 'stroke',
            selectionBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
        }));
        canvas.renderAll(); 
    })
```

tanks for any attempt

Comment: Make a snippet /jsfiddle to show the issue. As I see it clears the canvas when image is loaded, nothing wrong in itext

Answer (score 2):

okay guys after hours of code storming ive found how to do it ,

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('tcanvas', {
        hoverCursor: 'pointer',
        preserveObjectStacking: true, ////this prevents it from rearranging on the z axis 
        selection: true,
    });
```

this isnt enough to keep it with the image at the background in a scenerio that the image is added after the text so u use

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, (img) => {
  canvas.clear();
  canvas.add(img);
  canvas.sendToBack(img);
```

});

thats that tank you all

Comment: Glad you found a way to complete my answer to make it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is weird, by default latest added objects are on the top of the drawn objects' stack. Anyway if you need only one image as background, you might want to use

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, (img) => {
      canvas.clear();
      canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, () => { 
// handle promise resolution here if you want to });
});
```

If you don't want - maybe several images, maybe something else - you also can use

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, (img) => {
      canvas.clear();
      canvas.add(img);
      canvas.sendToBack(img);
});
```

which forces your image to be positioned at the bottom of the drawn objects' stack.

Comment: hey did what u said @mozgor and tanks but it works till i tap on the image the after doing that the image now goes on top and covers the text  i would prefer the image stay at the bak permanently tanks

Comment: any idea whats up with it tanks for ur input